# Does Captain America have to lose that character again?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, towards the end, we see Captain America being sent back in time to restore the Stones, and he chooses to remain back in time and live his life with Peggy Carter.

Does he then have to experience the Snapocalypse, likely losing Peggy in the process, but knowing in 5 years she'd come back?

Answer (score 7):

Peggy Carter died in 2016, during the events of *Captain America: Civil War*. She wasn't snapped. The time travel rules in *Endgame* (as in any time travel movie) can bring brain knots, but as Captain looked really relaxed in the end, I think she might have just died of old age, after what he returned to the "present".

Why would he have left her otherwise? Banner does say he can take "all the time he needs".

Answer (score -2):

Captain America's timeline is a bit tricky to explain. But as many characters in the movie said, the things that happened in the past cannot change. Here is what I interpreted from the movie. **There is only one Steve Rogers**

Steve Rogers, goes back in time to return the stones taken from different moments in time. He returns the Space stone aka Tessarect last. The Tessarect was taken from Peggy's timeline so he spends his life with her & grows older with her. But he must return to the present otherwise there would be two Steve's. Events done in the past don't change the future. Steve went down with the plane in The First Avenger. He was found before Avenger's movie stuck in ice. That timeline continues as it is. In Civil War, we see Steve(the original, younger version) at Peggy's funeral. The events continue till the beginning of Infinity War.

But younger Thanos is killed through Snap. So Thanos's story end there. Infinity War doesn't take place or to be more clear, Snap doesn't take place.

Comment: It's clearly established that the snap did take place as did the rest of Infinity War. The split timeline when Thanos comes forward is the one that is erased.

Comment: @Paulie_D but since Young Thanos dies then who does the snap in the Infinity War.

Comment: The alternate timeline gets erased and Thanos never comes forwards...so Past Thanos carries out the events of Infinity War because Cap returned the Stones.

Comment: @Paulie_D but then it's a loop no. So Thanos will snap, Avengers will unsnap. Thanos will snap again & Avengers will unsnap. I thought I it figured. But now I am confused even more

Comment: Yeah but it's a closed loop. Thanos can't snap again since he destroyed the stones. The Avengers don't care that they are now destroyed because they undid the snap. There was a snap, that *happened* as did everything that happened in the 5 years before it got unsnapped....and Thanos is now dead after Thor killed him.